# Spring scheduled fixedRateString as Duration

Tags: java, spring, cron, scheduling

The `@Scheduled` [documentation here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/Scheduled.html) states that the `fixedRateString` value can be `the delay in milliseconds as a String value, e.g. a placeholder or a java.time.Duration compliant value`. Meaning I can either write

```
@Scheduled(fixedRateString = "45s")
```

OR

```
@Scheduled(fixedRateString = "45000")
```

And it should be the same. However when I try to run it I get

```
Encountered invalid @Scheduled method 'updateWarmupInstances': Invalid fixedRateString value "45s" - cannot parse into long
```

So it this a mistake on Spring's part or am I doing something wrong
?

Comment: FYI an issue was opened recently requesting flexible duration parsing of the kind you and I both expected. Turns out it's a Spring framework issue, not Spring Boot: github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/22013

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking at the return value of the method, not the input. The input can only be a String in milliseconds, but the return value is a value compliant with Duration.

Comment: Return value of… what method?  The `fixedRateString` attribute of the annotation?  Or are you suggesting that the annotated method can return either a String or Duration to describe the frequency with which it will be called?

Answer (score 11):

To use the method @Scheduled(fixedRateString) for durations, you could use a String with the standard duration:

```
@Scheduled(fixedRateString = "PT45S")
```

The prefix PT is for [ISO-8601 standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations) and in this example, it's mean the duration of 45 seconds.

Another example could be a duration of 1h:

```
@Scheduled(fixedRateString = "PT1H")
```